# populate array from list onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, arrays

I 'm writing a code with JS and I don't know how to populate array when clicking on button. We have this code, which uses a list (ul), where the items (li) can be moved with mouse. How can do onclick to populate an array with 2 data, its first position and the last position?

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( ".documents" ).sortable();
        $( ".documents" ).disableSelection();
      });
    </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>toArray demo</title>
  <style>
  span {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

Reversed - <span></span>

<ul id="opciones" class="documents">
<li>uno</li>
<li>dos</li>
<li>tres</li>
</ul>

<script>
function disp( li ) {
  var a = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ) {
    a.push( li[ i ].innerHTML );
  }
  $( "span" ).text( a.join( " " ) );
}
disp( $( "li" ).toArray() );
</script>
 <input type="button" value="actualizar_array" onclick="disp('#opciones')" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like this.  What you're looking for is the `.each` method.

```
   function updateOrder(){
        var a= [];

        $("#opciones li").each(function(i, li){
            a.push($(li).text());
        });

        // a now has the values of your list items in order
        // so you can do:
        $( "#display" ).text( a.join( " " ) );

    }
```

Using the sortable plugin you can call updateOrder from a 'sortupdate' event:

```
$('#opciones').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function() {
    updateOrder();
});
```

I made a little fiddle for you to demonstrate.  http://jsfiddle.net/56Sr2/5/

Comment: thanks, all gone ok, i have entered the position only changing class name for item_X and including one line to your code, thanks. the line: orderArray.push($("li")[i].className.slice(5));

Again, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `disp()` you are treating the argument (li) like an array, but you are sending it as a string: `disp('#opciones')`. I think you want to try this:

```
function disp( ul ) {
    var a = [];
    var mainUL = document.getElementByID( ul );
    var li = mainUl.childNodes;
    for ( var i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ) {
        a.push( li[ i ].innerHTML );
    }
    $( "span" ).text( a.join( " " ) );
}
```

And call it using `disp("opciones")` instead of `disp('#opciones')`.